# How to fix 'Access has been blocked by CORS policy' in React/Node.js application

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, cors, fetch-api

I have a web application that I am building using React on the front end and Node.js on the back end. My API is functioning fine when I make calls using postman, but when I try to make a call using fetch, it fails and I get the error:

"Access to fetch at 'XXXURL' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

First, I tried disabling cors by setting request mode to no-cors in the request options. This didn't work as the error went away but the request did not go through.

Next, I tried adding the following piece of middle ware to my code:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  // Website you wish to allow to connect
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

  // Request methods you wish to allow
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE"
  );

  // Request headers you wish to allow
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "X-Requested-With,content-type"
  );

  // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
  // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);

  // Pass to next layer of middleware
  next();
});
```

Same error, nothing changed.

Then, I tried installing cors and using the following code:

```
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: ["http://localhost:5173/", "http://127.0.0.1:5173/", "*", null],
  })
);
```

Same error. I have tried several different origins and nothing has worked. I have run out of resources online and am not sure what it could be. I have closed and reopened VSCode multiple times and still nothing. Please help me I am losing it.

Here is my fetch call and api:

Fetch call

```
async function getFighterStats() {
      dispatch({ type: "getFighters/start" });

      try {
        const requestOptions = {
          method: "GET",
          headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        };
        const res = await fetch(
          `http://127.0.0.1:3000/app/v1/fighters/`,
          requestOptions
        );
        const data = await res.json();

        dispatch({ type: "getFighters/finish", payload: data });
      } catch {
        dispatch({
          type: "rejected",
          payload: "There was an error calling API...",
        });
      }
    }
```

API

app.js

```
import express from "express";
import fighterRouter from "./routes/fighterRoutes.js";
import predictionRouter from "./routes/predictionRoutes.js";
import cors from "cors";

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: ["http://localhost:5173/", "http://127.0.0.1:5173/", "*", null],
  })
);

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  // Website you wish to allow to connect
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

  // Request methods you wish to allow
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE"
  );

  // Request headers you wish to allow
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "X-Requested-With,content-type"
  );

  // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
  // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);

  // Pass to next layer of middleware
  next();
});

app.use("/app/v1/fighters", fighterRouter);
app.use("/app/v1/prediction", predictionRouter);

export default app;
```

fighterRoutes.js

```
import express from "express";
import {
  getAllFighters,
  addFighter,
  getFighter,
  checkID,
} from "../controllers/fighterController.js";

const router = express.Router();

router.param("id", checkID);

router.route("/").get(getAllFighters).post(addFighter);

router.route("/:id").get(getFighter);

export default router;
```

fighterController.js

```
import fs from "fs";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

const fighters = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(`./data/fighterData.json`));

const checkID = (req, res, next, val) => {
  console.log(`fighter ID is: ${val}, it is of type ${typeof val}`);
  const results = fighters.find((el) => el.id === val); // REMEMBER TO CHANGE TO el._id
  if (!results) {
    return res.status(404).json({ status: "fail", message: "Invalid ID" });
  }
  next();
};

const getAllFighters = (req, res) => {
  console.log(fighters);
  res.status(200).json({
    status: "success",
    results: fighters.length,
    data: {
      fighters,
    },
  });
};
```

Comment: frtst mistake ... `Content-Type` in a GET request? second issue `preflight request` - your server doesn't handle CORS preflight requests - though, that may be resolved by fixing the first problem

Comment: @CraZyDroiD worst advice ever

Comment: See if `app.use(cors())` works first. If it does, it's most likely an issue of your cors config param. Also, the other middleware is a bit redundant, so I suggest you to remove it.

Answer (score 2):

I used CORS package in my several projects. And I configured as below.

```js
//... rest of the above code.

var whitelist = ['http://localhost:5173', 'http://127.0.0.1:5173']
var corsOptions = {
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
      callback(null, true)
    } else {
      callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
    }
  }
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions)); // define this middeware before the all routes as you defined.
```

And make sure you are browsing your React app from `whitelist`.

You don't need to set headers configuration manually. Just comment that code.

Answer (score 2):

I removed the cors module and added the following middleware and it worked today

```html
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
  next();
});
```

It's basically the same as the other middle ware so maybe my computer was just having issues, but thank you everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly install cors:

```
npm i cors
```

Then add this statement in **`app.js` (main file)**:

```
app.use(cors())
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).